# Auto-completion suggestions from parse error

Tags: parsing, haskell, megaparsec

I am writing a parser for a custom jupter kernel using megaparsec. I was able to re-use the parser to provide completions too: the custom error message generated from the megaparsec library are transformed to the list of expected symbols. It that way, whenever I change the parser, completion automatically adjust itself. Which is great.

The only thing I am struggling is how to get info from the *optional* parsers. The minimal example illustrating what I want to achieve is following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Control.Applicative
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char
import qualified Text.Megaparsec.Char.Lexer as L
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Set (singleton)

type Parser = Parsec MyError Text

data MyError = ExpectKeyword Text deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

lexeme = L.lexeme sc
sc = L.space (skipSome (oneOf [' ', '\t'])) empty empty

-- | Reserved words
rword :: Text -> Parser Text
rword w = region (fancyExpect (ExpectKeyword w)) $
          lexeme (string w *> return w)

fancyExpect f e = FancyError (errorPos e) (singleton . ErrorCustom $ f)

p1 = rword "foo" <|> rword "bar"

p2 = (<>) <$> option "def" (rword "opt") <*> p1

main = do
  putStrLn . show $ parse p1 "" ("xyz" :: Text) -- shows "foo" and "bar" in errors
  putStrLn . show $ parse p2 "" ("xyz" :: Text) -- like above, no optional "opt"
```

In the first case, parser fails and I get the list of all errors from all alternatives. Ideally, in the second case I would like to see the error of the failed optional parser too.

This example can be simply solved by removing `option` and making two branches with `<|>`: one with option and the other without. However in real case the optional part is a permutation parser consisting of several optional parts, so such trick is not feasible.

Comment: This is weird, since `option x p = p <|> pure x` be definition, so I can't see why making two branches as you say would help, since it would be equivalent to `p <|> p <|> pure x`.

Comment: By making two branches I meant parser: `p3 = ((<>) <$> rword "opt" <*> p1) <|> p1`. That parser in custom error reports that it expects "foo", "bar" or "opt". While `p2` informs only on "foo" and "bar", despite the fact that "opt" would be fine too.

Comment: However, your comment explains why `option` does produce custom error: `pure` is parser that always succeeds, so the whole `option` parser does not need any input to succeed. The question is still valid: how elegantly get what is expected by optional parser.

Comment: Is using `label` / `<?>` of any help for your issue? It is not the same, but...